# Not able to access Request.Headers in BeginExecuteCore() method of Basecontroller MVC4

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Can any one please help me? I am trying to implement localization in my mvc 4 WebApi application. I want to show the culture specific pages to the user on the basis of 
"User-Locale" passed in the Request headers.

What I have done is, I am having a LinkedAccountModel class as shown below -

```
 public class LinkedAccountModel
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DomainNameRequired")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "DomainName", ResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource))]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequired")]
    [Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordRequired")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource))]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ServerNameRequired")]
    [Display(Name = "ServerName", ResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Resource))]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
}
```

========================================================================

With this, I am having an ExchangeAccountSetupController which uses this model. This controller is implemented by the BaseController. My ExchangeAccountSetupController looks like as follows-

```
public class ExchangeAccountSetupController : BaseController
{
    private PersistenceManagerAsync _persistenceManager;

    public async Task<ActionResult> New(string sessionToken)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionToken))
        {               
            ViewBag.Title = LanguageResources.Resource.AccountConfigurationFailed;
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = LanguageResources.Resource.UnableToProcessRequest;

            return View("Message");
        }

        _persistenceManager = new PersistenceManagerAsync(null);
        var token = await _persistenceManager.RetrieveAsync<SessionToken>(string.Format("{0}|{1}", sessionToken.Substring(0, 10), sessionToken));
        if (token == null)
        {                
            ViewBag.Title = LanguageResources.Resource.AccountConfigurationFailed;
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = LanguageResources.Resource.UnableToProcessRequest;
            return View("Message");
        }

        _persistenceManager = new PersistenceManagerAsync(token);
        var user = new User { UserId = token.UserId };
        var linkedAccount = await LinkedAccountManager.RetrieveLinkedAccount(_persistenceManager, user, "Exchange");
        var linkedAccountModel = new LinkedAccountModel { UserId = token.UserId };

        var existingUser = await _persistenceManager.RetrieveAsync<User>(user.PartitionKey, user.RowKey);          
        if (linkedAccount != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = LanguageResources.Resource.ChangePassword;

            linkedAccountModel.DomainName = linkedAccount.DomainName;
            linkedAccountModel.UserName = linkedAccount.UserName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedAccount.Url))
                linkedAccountModel.ServerName = new Uri(linkedAccount.Url).Host;
            return View("New", linkedAccountModel);
        }
        ViewBag.Title = LanguageResources.Resource.ConfigureNewExchangeAccount; //default title.
        return View("New", linkedAccountModel);
    }
```

========================================================================

My BaseController looks like as follows -

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string currentLocale = string.Empty;
        if (Request.Headers["User-Locale"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["User-Locale"]))
            currentLocale = "en-US";
        else
            currentLocale = Request.Headers["User-Locale"];
        // Modify current thread's cultures                        
        string[] localeKeys = currentLocale.Split('-');
        if (localeKeys[0].Equals("en"))
            currentLocale = "en-US";
        else if (localeKeys[0].Equals("nl"))
            currentLocale = "nl-NL";
        else
            currentLocale = "en-US";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(currentLocale);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
}
```

========================================================================

My client application is in Dotnet only. I am sending a request to the "ExchangeAccountSetupController" controller's New() Action.

Here is the client application code where I am adding headers in my HttpClient Request-

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
```

client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Locale", "nl-NL");

var webResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(RestServiceUrl.GetLinkedAccountProviderUrl(accountProviderName)).Result;
            if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return null;

```
        var url = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(webResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        return url;
```

My problem is that whenever I send a request from my client, the request reached to BaseController successfully.But I cannot access that "User-Locale" in the current Request object under BeginExecuteCore() method. I cannot access the "User-Locale" header from the Request object. I did not get any thing in Request.Headers["User-Locale"].It give me null.

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.Even I am not sure whether I can access that header under BeginExecuteCore() method or not .Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `User-Locale` header defined in HTTP. You are probably looking for the `Accept-Language` header.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4
From MVC Web API you can get a hold of it with
`Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage`.

You can also get a parsed list of languages with this property
`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages`
Please note that the list is NOT sorted, contrary to what the documentation says.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages(v=vs.110).aspx